# How to delete row with timedelta value lower than 0?

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

How can I delete rows which have values of timedelta < 0:

```
Index     Date/Time               id           Timedelta
8      2019-09-09 07:31:37.979  2555        0 days 00:40:00.033000
9      2019-09-09 07:32:38.006  2555        0 days 00:01:00.027000
10     2019-09-09 07:32:37.938  2555        -1 days +23:59:59.932000
11     2019-09-09 11:22:38.154  2555        0 days 03:50:00.216000
12     2019-09-09 13:04:38.138  2555        0 days 01:41:59.984000
```

Desired result is

```
Index     Date/Time               id           Timedelta
8      2019-09-09 07:31:37.979  2555        0 days 00:40:00.033000
9      2019-09-09 07:32:38.006  2555        0 days 00:01:00.027000
11     2019-09-09 11:22:38.154  2555        0 days 03:50:00.216000
12     2019-09-09 13:04:38.138  2555        0 days 01:41:59.984000
```

Thank you

Comment: it's worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `'inverse'` logic - filter all rows with `Timedelta` higher or equal `0`:

```
df1 = df[df['Timedelta'] >= pd.Timedelta(0)]
```

Or compare days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
df1 = df[df['Timedelta'].dt.days >= 0]
```